# YoY comparison in Qlikview using Dimension values

Tags: qlikview

Can we do a year on year comparison using the dimension input in an expression? This is what I am trying to do. My dimension is Year and in the expression I want to show the total sales (e.g) for the selected dimension as that of the previous year?

It should look something like this:

```
Year       Current sale     Last year
2013          1000               1500
2012          1500               1200
2011          1200               1100
```

Is this doable or is it something I have to accommodate for in the data modelling layer?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using straight table, you need to accommodate this on your data model layer, but if you're using this with another dimension, and only showing single year, you can use set analysis:

```
    Current Year Expression: SUM({$<Year={$(=MAX(Year))}>}Sales)
    Last Year Expression: SUM({$<Year={$(=MAX(Year)-1)}>}Sales)
```